# int.TryParse Datagridview textbox which is sending null value when empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, tryparse

I want to parse a value. But gridview textbox is sending null value when empty.

```
int qty = 0;
int.TryParse(dgvInvoiceItems[dgvInvoiceItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index, 
e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out qty);
```

dgvInvoiceItems[dgvInvoiceItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index, 
    e.RowIndex].Value is null. When I try to convert it to string it throws exception.
And If I don't convert it take it as an object which is not allowed in TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.?` and `??` to use a default value if the object is null:

```
int.TryParse(dgvInvoiceItems[dgvInvoiceItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value?.ToString() ?? "0", out int qty);
```

or

```
int.TryParse((dgvInvoiceItems[dgvInvoiceItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value ?? 0).ToString(), out int qty);
```

Comment: Thanks. It Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ternary operator to check whether cell contains null or not, if null pass empty string !

```
int.TryParse(dgvInvoiceItems[dgvInvoiceItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value != null  ?
                                dgvInvoiceItems[dgvInvoiceItems.Columns["Quantity"].Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() : "", out qty);
```